# How to read environment variable in Glibc code

Tags: c, glibc

I want to disable/enable `printf()` output to screen by reading an environment variable, similar to how `LD_DEBUG` works.

I want to control `./stdio-common/printf.c`.

So if in environment variable says disable printf() it call

```
int
__printf (const char *format, ...)
{
  return done;
}
```

else it executes the original code. How would I implement this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8742414/841108 for a possible way of doing debug printf-s, if that is what you have in mind.

Comment: But you really should not disable the *system* 's `printf` (because you have no idea if other parts of the system are expecting it to work, and because the C standard defines its behavior).

Answer (score 4):

Use `getenv`. See `getenv(3)` for details.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use the solution provided by ANSI as `getenv()` function for maximum portability:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char * env = getenv(“PROMPT”)); 

    if(env)
        puts(env);
    else
    puts(“The environmental variable not available”);

    return 0;
}
```

There are other non-standard ways of doing the same which is not recommended.

The third argument to `main()` could be `char **envp` is used widely to get the information about the environment and is `non-standard`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    while(*envp)
        printf("%s\n",*envp++);
}
```

Using the third argument in `main()` is *not* strictly conforming to standard.

There is another widely used non-standard way of accessing the environmental variables and that is through the `environ` external variable.

```
int i=0;
extern char ** environ;

while(environ[i])
    printf("\n%s",environ[i++]);
```

NOTE: The examples are in-complete and lacks error handling.